# "Value does not fall within the expected range" when binding a JSON object in C#

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to test the connection from a MovieDB and bind a movies data to two parameters. But I only get this error:

> "Value does not fall within the expected range".

I can't figure out why this error is being thrown...any thoughts?

If I make a breakpoint right before the `MovieList.ItemsSource = deserialized` i can see that it contains all the data from the movie...

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox x:Name="MovieList" Height="532">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding original_title}" 
                 Margin="0,0,12,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding poster_path}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

---

```
private async void KopplaDB()
{
     var baseAddress = new Uri("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/");
     var key = "?api_key=*************************************";
     using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
     {          
          httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept", "application/json");

          using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("movie/550" + key))
          { 
              string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
              var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(responseData);
              MovieList.ItemsSource = deserialized;
          }
     }
}
```

Movie class:

```
class Movie
{  
    public bool adult { get; set; }
    public string backdrop_path { get; set; }
    public object belongs_to_collection { get; set; }
    public int budget { get; set; }
    public List<Genre> genres { get; set; }
    public string homepage { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string imdb_id { get; set; }
    public string original_language { get; set; }
    public string original_title { get; set; }
    public string overview { get; set; }
    public double popularity { get; set; }
    public string poster_path { get; set; }
    public List<ProductionCompany> production_companies { get; set; }
    public List<ProductionCountry> production_countries { get; set; }
    public string release_date { get; set; }
    public int revenue { get; set; }
    public int runtime { get; set; }
    public List<SpokenLanguage> spoken_languages { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string tagline { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public bool video { get; set; }
    public double vote_average { get; set; }
    public int vote_count { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the entire error/stacktrace?

Comment: StackTrace "   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemsControl.put_ItemsSource(Object value)\r\n   at MovieTime.MainPage.<KopplaDB>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c__DisplayClass2.<ThrowAsync>b__3(Object state)\r\n   at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()" string

Comment: Can we see your Properties in `Movie` object?  I'm assuming something is marked as a type it shouldn't, so it doesn't deserialize correctly.

Comment: Sure i have edit my post to include it..

Comment: Your positive the Json is valid for those `List`?  When it tries to see that collection?

Comment: Well like i said, if i break and look at the movie object i can se every thing even the stuff in the List-props

Comment: Doesn't mean it is valid Json though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this

```
<StackPanel>
<ListBox x:Name="MovieList" Height="532">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding original_title}" 
             Margin="0,0,12,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding poster_path}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

to

```
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding original_title}" 
             Margin="0,0,12,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding poster_path}"/>
            </StackPanel>
```

and in your code

```
this.DataContext = movieItem;
```